# How to compute a definite Integral in C++?

Tags: c++

How can you define a function to calculate the value of a definite integral in C++? For example to solve the integral of the function `x^2 * cos(x)`?

Comment: Sorry, VC++ is not a language. Visual Studio is an IDE and compiler.  I don't know how to evaluate an integral using an IDE.  Maybe there are some editor commands that could help.

Comment: My crystal ball (a.k.a. Google) says yes, there are libraries out there.  Actually, there have been libraries and algorithms for evaluating integrals since 1970 (maybe before).

Comment: Your edit would just change the close reason to "too broad", it doesn't justify reopening. Stack Overflow is for specific questions about coding that can have definite correct answers, not a place to ask open-ended questions seeking broad overviews, tutorials, introductory info, or general pointers about getting started. Please read the [Tour] page and the following advice on asking good questions: [[ask]], [[Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints)].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly enough, I ran across this article a little while ago explaining one method for calculating numerical integrals using function pointers.

https://helloacm.com/c-function-to-compute-numerical-integral-using-function-pointers/

For something like x^2 * cos(x):

You would need an overloaded integral function:

```
double integral(double(*f)(double x), double(*g)(double x, double y), double a, double b, int n)
{
    double step = (b - a)/n;   // width of rectangle
    double area = 0.0;
    double y = 0;  // height of rectangle

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        y = f(a + (i + 0.5) * step) * g(a + (i + 0.5) * step, y);
        area += y * step  // find the area of the rectangle and add it to the previous area. Effectively summing up the area under the curve.
    }

    return area;
}
```

To call:

```
int main()
{
    int x = 3;
    int low_end = 0;
    int high_end = 2 * M_PI;
    int steps = 100;
    cout << integral(std::powf, std::cosf, low_end, high_end, steps);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works. but i want to integral a term something this: x^2*cosx. do you have any idea?